# vue element-ui get index of table row

Tags: vue.js, html-table, row, element-ui

I want to add a button only to the first row of a table column (labeled with 'Option' in the example code). Is there any simple way to check the row index for v-if `v-if="scope.row.index === 0"` ?  `scope.row.index` wont work here.

```html
<el-table :data="mydata">
<!-- more columns -->
  <el-table-column prop="option" label="Option">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      <div v-if="scope.row.index === 0">
        <el-row>
          <el-col>
            <el-input v-model="scope.row.option"/>
          </el-col>
          <el-col>
            <el-button @click="">Check</el-button>
          </el-col>
      </el-row></div>
      <div v-else>
        <el-input v-model="scope.row.option" />
      </div>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
<!-- more columns -->
</el-table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution to this by using the `$index` variable, which is the index of the current row.

```html
<div v-if="scope.$index === 0">
```

Comment: What if you filter the data or sort them? This won't work anymore I think...

Answer (score 2):

vue `template` & `scope.$index`

my solution:

```html
 <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    border
    class="app-downlaod-guide-table"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      v-for="({
        prop,
        label,
        align,
        width,
        slot,
      }, i) in channelClomuns"
      :key="prop + i"
      :prop="prop"
      :width="width"
      :align="align"
      :label="label">
      <template
        slot-scope="scope"
        v-if="prop === `putLink`">
        <a
          target="_blank"
          href="tableData[scope.$index].putLink">
          {{tableData[scope.$index].putLink}}
        </a>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
```

Comment: What if you filter the data or sort them? This won't work anymore I think...